# python nested Tags (beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I used beautiful soup using python to get data from a specific website
but I don't know how to get one of these prices but I want the price in gram (g)
AS shown below this is the HTML codeL:

```
<div class="promoPrice margBottom7">16,000 
L.L./200g<br/><span class="kiloPrice">79,999 
L.L./Kg</span></div>
```

I use this code:

`p_price = product.findAll("div{"class":"promoPricemargBottom7"})[0].text`

my result was:
`16,000 L.L./200g 79,999 L.L./Kg`

but i want to have:
16,000 L.L./200g 
only

Comment: You can just filter out g ones separately after you get all these.

Comment: yes but how????

Comment: these come in a list right?

Comment: replace 'g' by 'g\t'. Now, split on '\t'. Now, check if string has 'Kg' if yes then ignore, if no, then you get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to first [decompose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) the span inside the `div` element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """
<div class="promoPrice margBottom7">16,000 L.L./200g<br/>
<span class="kiloPrice">79,999 L.L./Kg</span></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
element = soup.find("div", {'class': 'promoPrice'})
element.span.decompose()
print(element.text)
#16,000 L.L./200g
```

Comment: your answer works fine too, thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

*Try using `soup.select_one('div.promoPrice').contents[0]`*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="promoPrice margBottom7">16,000 L.L./200g<br/>
<span class="kiloPrice">79,999 L.L./Kg</span></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

# value = soup.select('div.promoPrice > span')  # for 79,999 L.L./Kg
value = soup.select_one('div.promoPrice').contents[0]
print(value)
```

Prints

> ```
>  16,000 L.L./200g
> ```

Comment: i forget that is post this question

Comment: but thank you any way it works fine